# Searching file for two strings with no duplicates, cut paste into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, scripting

I have a file of configs. I am trying to get my python code to search for two different strings in a text file, copy (Cut would make my life so much easier) and paste them into a text file without duplicates. My code is working for just one string and every time I try to make it do two it will either not work or only find the lines with both strings.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import sys
with open("ns-batch.bak.txt") as f:
lines = f.readlines()
lines = [l for l in lines if "10.42.88.192" 
in l]
with open("Py_parse2.txt", "w") as f1:
    f1.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: First off, please fix your indentation. You probably want to define what is "without duplicates". You did only search for one string after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's my take on things.

Assuming that you are looking for certain strings within each line, and then want to "copy" those lines to another file to see in which lines those strings were found, this, for example, should work:

```
lines = list()

with open("ns-batch.bak.txt", "r") as orig_file:
    for line in orig_file:
        if ("12.32.45.1" in line) or ("27.82.1.0" in line): #if "12.32.45.1" in line:
            lines.append(line)

with open("Py_parse2.txt", "x") as new_file:
    for line in lines:
        new_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Depending on how many strings you are looking for on each line, you can either add or remove `in` statements on line 5 of my example code (I also provided an example line of code on the same line that demonstrates only needing to find one string on a line, which I commented out). The `import sys` statement does absolutely nothing in this case; the `sys` module/package is not needed to do this work, so do not include that `import` statement. If you want to learn more about file I/O, check out this link ( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=write ) and go to section "7.2 Reading and Writing Files".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and linking me to more information for some extra learning! I appreciate you!

Comment: Yep. Your welcome! And I'll leave you with two tips: one, make sure you properly indent your Python code with "whitespace", and two, you can look up  a good many things Python related on the Python documentation website ( https://docs.python.org/3/ ).